# Error: .ini file does not include supervisorctl section

Tags: 16.04, supervisor

Supervisorctl doesn't seem to let me in:

```
$ supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
Error: .ini file does not include supervisorctl section
For help, use /usr/bin/supervisorctl -h
$ cat /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf 
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
```

I have both specified the config and `[supervisord]`. Is it possible my config is in the wrong place?

Comment: No, the notice seems to indicate it wants a "supervisorctl" section. Not "supervisord"?

Comment: I've found that if you execute /usr/bin/supervisord from a directory that has a copy of your supervisor.conf or other *.conf that this freaks supervisor out.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Adding a blank `[supervisorctl]` section seems to resolve the issue for me:

```
$ cat /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf 
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[supervisorctl]
```

Answer (score 7):

In the supervisor version 3+, I had to add the following in the conf file to make it work:

```
[inet_http_server]         
port=127.0.0.1:9001

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=http://127.0.0.1:9001
```

or you may use unix socket as:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/run/supervisord.sock

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///run/supervisord.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

The same error troubled me.

There is an issue in their github https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/376

Find out the path matters.

In `/etc/supervisor/` path of my server.

```
/etc/supervisor# ls
conf.d  supervisord.conf
```

Some change was made in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d`. I did most change from the issue above, not helping.

Then I inspired by this comment https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/376#issuecomment-404385767
After `cd ..` ie. move to `/etc/supervisor/` it works fine.

Hope this can help others.

Answer (score 0):

I had duplicate supervisord.conf files. One empty file "/etc/supervisord.conf" which was being used, and the other one at "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf" which I thought was the one being used. I deleted the empty file (/etc/supervisord.conf) and the error was gone.